# Where can I find Xcode Terms and Definitions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, definition

At the moment I am learning how to use Xcode and objective C to make iOS apps - and all is going well.

I come across a lot of terms which I think are language specific and I was wondering is there a website that explains these are?

Terms like setter, class, subclass etc. I am starting to understand what they are, but it would be good, to find a sort of dictionary for these.

So I am familiar with the reading of the terms, but I want to learn what they all mean, so I can make more sense of the code, beyond basic manipulation:-)

Is there a website for this??

EDIT:

Take for example this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com";    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

I know what it does, but I am unsure of how to write this from scratch - even though it's simple - I guess if I knew what part is called what then I could say that I could remember it in a logical sense.

I could say I need an NSString with the name urladdress - but is this a Class with an object? that kinda stuff:-)

-Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples you mentioned are not Xcode or even Objective-C specific.

But a good start is Apples Objective-C document, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf

Comment: Yeah I guess - but is there a place that explains how they relate in those environments? I am going to through that file you posted, but I am more after something for quick reference.

Comment: If you are already familiar with object oriented programming you may want to have a look at the document mentioned by @Jim if not the Objective C doc that I linked to maybe the most efficient way. ALthough it all depends on what you want to do. If you elaborate more maybe we can help better.

Comment: If you want to do this seriously, you need to learn the basics of object oriented programming, and there are lots and lots of books and videos and ... out there, if I understad it correctly you don't have a deep enough understanding of OO programming. On top of that Objective C (being a supper set of C) has some additional features that you can read in the Apple docs mentioned before. ObjectiveC + frameworks provided by apple makes a sweet environment. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks:-) yeah I have tackled some books, but somehow I need to find a way to understand it more, so I am just trying to find a way to get to that point - I am a visual learner, so I am better at manipulating the code - but the downside of that is that I do not learn the terminology and probably attract some bad coding habits:-)

Comment: It's not just te terminology, there are some concepts that you need to learn, which are more or less called the same name in different OO languages. So when you learn them in one you can easily understand them in other languages as well. Don't be discouraged though. I am sure You'll master it soon.

Answer (score 2):

"Setter", "class" and "subclass" are all object-oriented programming concepts.  They aren't specific to Xcode or Objective-C.  Apple provide a high-level overview in [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html).